# how does tortoise git get commit information?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

A strange question here. I need to filter out some part of any commit message in a repo (it's a long hash automatically added after some migration).
As I'm (and my team also) using tortoise git, I created a small wrapper over git which basically forwards everything to stdout except the hashes from the commit messages.
My assumption was that tortoise git would eventually call git log.
Indeed, my wrapper works ie. when I do git log I get:

```
TICKETID-xxx
commit message
```

instead of

```
TICKETID-xxx
commit message
LONG-HASH
```

However, when I configure my git wrapper into tortoise git I still see the original commit messages. I already excluded an issue with my wrapper by logging its activity.

When I select the "Show log" option from the tortoise git I see the following commands being invoked:

```
git.exe symbolic-ref HEAD
git.exe rev-parse --revs-only --end-of-options HEAD
git.exe rev-parse --revs-only HEAD
git.exe update-index --refresh
git.exe diff-index --cached --raw HEAD --numstat -C -M -z --
git.exe diff-index --raw HEAD --numstat -C50% -M50% -z --
git.exe ls-files -u -t -z
git.exe ls-files -d -z
git.exe ls-files --exclude-standard --full-name --others -z
```

So how exactly is tortoise git displaying the commit messages?
One thing is certain, the commit information doesn't come from the stdout of git.exe otherwise I would see it in the log of my wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all functionality in TortoiseGit is implemented by shelling out to the Git executable. Instead, some of it relies on calling into [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/) or a fork of the Git source code compiled as a DLL named [tgit](https://github.com/TortoiseGit/tgit). It looks like the dialog shown with "Show log" uses the latter quite a bit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response, I understand that my approach can't possibly work. Would you have a different suggestion to get the functionality I need?

Comment: @SterpuMihai it's a bit unclear to me exactly what you're trying to do. I am not sure what hiding this information in a single Git client accomplishes. Is it just for convenience, or is it to hide sensitive information? There are ways to "rewrite history" in Git that would allow you to update all the commits to remove the long hash. If the problem is truly how to hide that specific information in TortoiseGit without modifying the commits, then I guess your best bet would be to modify the TortoiseGit source code as it is open-source.

Comment: It's just for convenience ie. better readability of the commit logs. The first issue is that the  commit logs don't follow the "subject convention" of git and have a ticket identifier followed by a newline. This was easily solvable by using the "Display subject and body of commit messages". However, due to a svn-git migration, some hashes were also added to each commit message. These hashes are quite annoying, https://imgur.com/a/BQgMUG7 my intention was to remove the hash part which is not interesting for us (but at the same time keep it in the commit messages for any possible future usage)

Comment: In the end I managed to modify tortoise git using visual studio 2022, thanks for the hint! :)